# Decision Tree sample count on main node doesn't match total count of observations

Tags: random-forest, decision-tree, sample

I have a dataset that includes 248 observations and I am trying to visualize a decision tree from a random forest model I put together. The article below suggests the sample value in the root node is the value of samples (observations) in the dataset. However, the sample value in the root node of my decision tree does not equal 248 and it equals 184 instead, as seen in the image below.

https://towardsdatascience.com/scikit-learn-decision-trees-explained-803f3812290d

[Root node of decision tree with wrong sample value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjmIG.png)

the code to my model is:

```
rf = RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=3,
                            n_estimators=30,
                            random_state=42,
                            bootstrap=False)
rf.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred_rf = rf.predict(X_test)
```

and the code to my tree is:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))

fig = tree.plot_tree(rf.estimators_[13], 
                     feature_names=x_df.columns,
                     class_names=y_train,
                     filled=True, 
                     impurity=True, 
                     rounded=True,
                     proportion=False)

fig = fig
```

Unfortunately, I can't share the data due to an NDA but does anyone know why the sample field on the root node of the tree does not equal 248?

Answer (score 0):

The sample size on the root node is 198 because the tree is based on the training data, not the entire dataset.